# cbuffer unexpected token DX11 examples

Tags: visual-studio, directx, buffer, token

On loading up a direct x 11 SDK project example, after linking all Libs./includes ETC that I was given an error from; I came across the following within an fx file.

VS version   :  VS ultimate 2013
Example name : 'DepthOfFeild10.1'
SDK          : 'Microsoft DirectX SDK (February 2010)'
fx file name : 'DepthOfField10.1.fx'
error        : Error    1   error X3000: syntax error: unexpected token 'cb0'

Perhaps I'm missing a lib/tool/set-up procedure ?
(Running Debug, X64)

Advice appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you are trying to use VS 2013 and the legacy DirectX SDK together, be sure to read [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx).

*You need to use a different include/lib/executable path order with VS 2012 and later than the default VS 2010 projects that come with the legacy DirectX SDK February 2010 and June 2010 releases.*

> Many of the legacy DirectX SDK samples have been updated to remove the need to use the legacy DirectX SDK at all since VS 2013 and the Windows 8.1 SDK are generally sufficient. These are published to [GitHub](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples). See [DirectX SDK Samples Catalog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/09/20/directx-sdk-samples-catalog.aspx). *DepthOfField10.1*, however, is not one of these because it's an AMD sample. You can find AMD's version of it in their [archive](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/graphics-development/amd-radeon-sdk/archive/).

Start with the DirectX SDK (June 2010) version of DepthOfField10.1 (install it from the sample browser).

Open the `DepthOfField10.1_2010.sln` file and let it Upgrade the VC++ Tools and Libraries to `v120`.

Edit the Project Properties -> VC++ Directories:

- For all configurations and the Win32 Platform, set it to:

Executable Directories: `$(ExecutablePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Utilities\bin\x86`
Include Directories: `$(IncludePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Include`
Library Directories: `$(LibraryPath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x86`

- For all configurations and the x64 Platform, set it to:

Executable Directories: `$(ExecutablePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Utilities\bin\x64;$(DXSDK_DIR)Utilities\bin\x86;`
Include Directories: `$(IncludePath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Include`
Library Directories: `$(LibraryPath);$(DXSDK_DIR)Lib\x64`

> If you were using VS 2015, then you also need to add the blog version of [DXERR](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/04/24/where-s-dxerr-lib.aspx) and remove the legacy DirectX SDK version of `dxerr.lib` from the project. A quick hack of DXUT is needed to resolve the ASCII/UNICODE differences. This is needed because VS 2015 includes some C99 related standard library changes that fail to link with the old version of `strsafe.h` used to build the legacy DirectX SDK.

Once this is done, it builds and runs as is.

> Note: Most of the Direct3D 10 samples in the legacy DirectX SDK make use of the old Effects (FX) system. There's a Direct3D 11 version of Effects available, but the HLSL compiler support for Effects is officially deprecated. See [Effects for Direct3D 11](https://github.com/Microsoft/FX11).

If the problem is happening in our own projects, then likely you have mis-configured the `FXC` command-line for building that .fx file.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions.
Although a I said in the question : I've allready done this linking; additionally I have changed the symbols to v120. Great to know I did it correctly however.

I did look into the FX issue, I have read that FX's are now run in the preprocessor and don't need to be included in build.

Just to reiterate here that this simple a direct installation of the examples with imported settings all included.

if you think of anything else that may help; or if you yourself have a settings file that works, a comparison would surely help.

I'll test again tomorrow and let you know.